# Quand utiliser « quel que » ou « quoi que » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, pronoms, pronoms-interrogatifs

*Quel que* et *quoi que* introduisent le plus souvent des subordonnées (conjuguées au subjonctif).

Il me semble que *quoi que* est proche de *quelle que soit la chose que*. Qu'en est-il exactement ? Quand utiliser l'un ou l'autre ?

Comment: Quel que/quelque [ici](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-41406.php) et [ici](http://www.projet-voltaire.fr/blog/regle-orthographe/quelque-ou-quel-que) et Quoi que / quoique : [ici](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-9153.php) et [ici](http://www.projet-voltaire.fr/blog/regle-orthographe/%C2%AB-quoique-%C2%BB-ou-%C2%AB-quoi-que-%C2%)

Comment: *Quel* et *quoi* ne sont pas des pronoms relatifs. *Que* est tout sauf un pronom. *Quelque* et *quoique* n'ont absolument rien à voir (et dans tous les cas ce serait une question distincte).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Merci de votre commentaire. Je suis dérouté; ainsi les différences d'usage (PAS de celles de grammaire) entre *Quelque* et *quoique* diffèrent de tout ci-dessus ?

Comment: Oui c'est complètement différent, il suffit de trouver un ou deux exemples dans un dictionnaire pour s'en rendre compte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On utilise le mot correspondant à la particule interrogative ([quel](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quel), [quoi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/que), …).

- « Quoi que » correspond à une question introduite par « que ». Il s'agit d'un objet ou d'un concept non déterminé.
- « Quel que » correspond à une question introduite par « quel » ou « lequel ». Il s'agit d'un choix parmi un ensemble de possibilités, ou d'une interrogation sur une caractéristique d'un objet déterminé.
- « Qui que » correspond à une question introduite par « qui ». Il s'agit d'une personne.
- « Où que » correspond à une question introduite par « où ». Il s'agit d'un lieu.
- On ne dit pas « quand que » ni « comment que » (je ne sais pas pourquoi), il faut utiliser d'autres tournures comme « à quelque moment que », « de quelque manière que », etc.

> Qu'en dis-tu ? Quoi que tu en dises, tu ne pourras pas l'empêcher.
>   Quelle est la couleur de ta voiture ? Quelle que soit la couleur de ta voiture, tu peux la garer ici.
>   Pour quel candidat vas-tu voter ? Quel que soit ton candidat favori, tu devrais aller voter.
>   Qui as-tu rencontré ? Qui que tu aies croisé, j'espère que tu as été poli avec lui.
>   Où vas-tu en vacances ? Où que tu ailles, je te souhaite un bon voyage.